# Olympic 50km race walk

Tags: olympics, racewalking

Recently saw an odd event in the Olympics: the 50km race walk

I was shown footage of the finish and it was someone walking up to the finish.

Obviously you are not allowed to run but

> What would happen if you did run (accidentally and purposefully) and how do they make sure you don't?

Comment: after two warnings you are out!

Comment: okay @fedorqui, what a weird sport!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the linked rules of International Association of Athletics Federations:

> **Red Cards**
>
> 5. When a Judge observes an athlete failing to comply with paragraph 1 (Race Walking is a progression of steps so taken that the walker makes contact with the ground, so that no visible (to the human eye) loss of contact occurs.)  above by exhibiting visible loss of contact or a bent knee during any
>      part of the competition, the Judge shall send a Red Card to the Chief
>      Judge.
>
> **Disqualification**
>
> 6. (a) **When three Red Cards from three different Judges** have been sent to the Chief Judge, the athlete is disqualified and he shall be
>      notified of this disqualification by the Chief Judge or a Chief
>      Judgeís Assistant by showing the athlete a red paddle. The failure to
>      give notification shall not result in the reinstatement of a
>      disqualified athlete.
>
>    (b) In all competitions, either directly controlled by the IAAF or
>      taking place under IAAF permit, in no circumstances shall the Red
>      Cards of two Judges of the same nationality have the power to
>      disqualify.

It takes three Red Cards from three different Judges for an athlete to be disqualified. You can visit the link and read more details on how it works.